# How do I replace empty cell in specific column dataframe with some value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe(df)

```
   A Column1      Column2
0  0  Value1              
1  1                    
2  2  Value2   some value
3  3  Value3
```

And I want the to replace all empty value from just column2 with specific string "Its Empty"

```
   A Column1      Column2
0  0  Value1     Its Empty         
1  1             Its Empty       
2  2  Value2    some value
3  3  Value3     Its Empty
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with assign `loc`

```
df.loc[df['Column2']=='','Column2'] = 'Its Empty'
```

Or `replace`

```
df['Column2'].replace({'':'Its Empty'},inplace=True)
```